# what's the differences between static initialization and dynamic initialization in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Recently when I do some practice on LeetCode,I find some trick solution.It use an Object o to reference an array`Object o = new Object[]{null,null};`,I guess maybe it's because in java everything is object.But when I tried this way,it went wrong.`Object o3 = {1,2};`So I tried every way to initialization a array and I want to see the difference,like these

```
int arr[] = {1,2};
Object o = arr;
Object o1 = new int[2];
Object o2 = new int[]{1,2};
Object o3 = {1,2};
```

Only the o3 will compile an error.I don't know if it's because the way of initialization.I know when I use static initialization it will allocate memory first,when use dynamic initialization it will not.Any other differences between them cause this error?When I use new to create a array.what did it do in jvm?Thanks in advance.

Comment: "in java everything is object" No, primitives are not Objects

Comment: One 'difference' is that there is no such thing as 'static initialization' in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initializer `{1,2}` is shorthand for `new int[] {1,2}`. This shorthand can only be used as an initializer for a variable of type `int[]`.<sup>1</sup> For instance, while the following works:

```
int arr[] = {1,2};
```

this doesn't:

```
int arr[];
arr = {1,2}; // ERROR
```

Instead, you would need to use:

```
int arr[];
arr = new int[] {1,2};
```

Similarly, you can use:

```
Object o3 = new int[] {1,2};
```

P.S. The above applies to `static` as well as instance fields, and also to local variables. Java doesn't have such a distinction as "static vs. dynamic initialization". That's more C++ terminology.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Well, it could also be for a variable of type `byte[]`, `long[]`,
 `float[]`, `Integer[]`, etc., for which the literals `1` and `2` are assignment compatible. See the [Section 10.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).</sub>

Comment: `{..}` literal array creation can be also performed with any reference type. Like: `String[] strings = {"one", "two"};`

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri - You are right, of course. Such arrays can be of any element type at all, whether primitive or reference. It seemed to me that OP was specifically interested in arrays initialized with integer literals, which is why I worded my response the way I did.